# Dealing with multiple images in MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am working on an android app that displays people's posts, a single post can have multiple images the way a facebook post can. At first I thought I could have an image column in my post table like

`| id | title | description | image |` but later realized that this was not a good technique since a single post could hold multi images, plan B was to have a seperate table to hold all image paths so the table would be like

`| id | postFk | imagePath |`, with this technique the problem is; How do I fetch both the post and images at the same time? A normal join is failing, well not really, its pulling data but I have all these repetitions and duplications, Anyone dealt with a similar problem?

Comment: can you post your query

Comment: here is the query `Select p.id, p.title. p.description, i.image from post_tb p JOIN image_tb i ON i.postFK = p.id`

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Left Join . A sample query below,

```
SELECT * FROM post_table AS u LEFT JOIN post_photo AS p ON p.userid = u.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You should filter out the multiplied post rows yourself when dealing whith the result of your query. You migth want to turn the result into a datastructure like

```
$posts = [
  [
    'title' => 'lorem',
    'description' => 'ipsum',
    'images' => [image1, image2,...],
  ],
  [another post]
]
```

Or you could use an ORM that does that job for you, like [Doctrine ORM](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/).

Btw way, your query selects only posts withat least one image. Use a LEFT JOIN if post can have no images too.

Comment: How do you use it? any tutorials?